# Laravel project deployment to live server from local development environment

Tags: laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel. It's really good application. I developed web application using laravel docs. But the problem is how to deploy it on live server.

In local development environment we use "php artisan serve" command and can access project from http://localhost:8000.
But what should be proper  way  to run it on live domain.  Please don't suggest me something like copy htaccess to root directory and rename server.php to index.php  etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest you to watch video from Youtube videos : [Move Laravel  to Live](https://youtu.be/wQMZld0Iroo)

This video help you to install to server ; after installing you may even just ise composer or by copying files to server you can run your  project in your live server.

Just be sure you installed laravel .

Of problem exists please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This .htaccess file will point to public/index.php file

```
DirectoryIndex public/index.php <IfModule mod_rewrite.c><IfModule mod_negotiation.c>Options -MultiViews</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]</IfModule>
```

Comment: @sorvary I placed this code in htaccess in root folder.  Than replaces with public htaccess file. In both conditions its not working